# Questionable review audit result

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I was just presented with this question in a review (Late Answers)
https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/18915162

I understand why "just a link" answers are not a good idea, but in this case, first of all, the link was to superuser and secondly, it really has something to do with the question and could be considered an answer.

I failed the audit, which is fine, and it's just a small case, but I was generally wondering, if it should have better been migrated or marked as a duplicate (and is it considered a "duplicate", although it's on superuser?)

Please understand, I am totally new to reviews and just found out, that my "guts-feeling" is a serious problem (not medically :-) ) and that I have to become much more conscious about the whole process. I wish there were an

[image]

Button when failing an audit :-)

Comment: The fact the link points to another SE site doesn't exempt it from the "link only" policy - it's certainly not an answer in itself.

Comment: C'mon meta effect!

Comment: @Will:  The answer was deleted from review yesterday, so the Meta effect would be wasted here.

Comment: @Makoto What do you mean by "the Meta effect"? I do not understand the last two comments ´-(

Comment: @Xan-KunClark-Davis https://www.google.com/search?q=meta+effect

Comment: @Makoto the question needs closing as off topic, however.

Comment: @Will:  I mean I *get* it, but I don't really see benefit to closing this question since it can't be migrated anywhere else. Some other preservation level perhaps, since it's still useful?

Comment: I didn't say delete it, I said close it. You close off topic questions because other people claim them as proof that *their* off topic questions are on topic. "Oh, look at this question, it's +16 and is about the same tool I've asked about!" No, no thanks.

Comment: @Servy oh I see now, you mean the meta effect in organic photochemistry. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if it should have better been migrated or marked as a duplicate

As a reviewer you're more than welcome to look at the question and see if either of those things would be appropriate.  Neither changes the appropriateness of *this answer*, but if you think the question belongs on SU, you're more than welcome to flag it for migration.  That said, if you think the question is a duplicate then *it doesn't merit migration*.  We only migrate *good* questions, not questions that are just going to need to be immediately closed.

> it really has something to do with the question and could be considered an answer.

No, it really can't.  It's just a link, it doesn't *answer the question*.  It *points to a possible answer elsewhere*, which isn't an answer.  "Has something to do with the question" doesn't make a post an answer.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up and teaching me some english (I didn't know 'merit' could also be a verb :-) ). For some reason, I have to wait 5 minutes before I can accept.

Answer (score 4):

A link is a link.  It doesn't matter if it links to Super User or even to an answer on Stack Overflow.  If it's only using the link as its only supporting crutch for the answer, then it's just as susceptible to changing tides and policies which cause dead links elsewhere on the internet.

My personal philosophy is to suggest to the OP that if the answer is on Stack Overflow, they should close it as a dupe.  Off-site links...well, they're not really answers, they're just pointers to answers, which isn't what we want.  Super User may wind up deleting that question/answer for any arbitrary reason and we'd be unable to "fix" it.

The question's too old to migrate; it was asked back in '13.  There's only a 60-day grace period to migrate questions.